# Delphi. Change TMemo of another form raises Exception

Tags: delphi, exception, tmemo

Today I face some problem: when I try add lines to TMemo on another form:

```
workingForm.scanLog.Lines.Add('Page ' + link + ' proceed.');
```

It's returning a error: [image]

What I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you initializing the workingForm?

Comment: check Assigned(workingForm) and Assigned(workingForm.scanLog)

Comment: `workingForm` is already loaded, I want access to it from another unit.

Comment: Is this the same thread that calls this method ? If not, you need to synchronize this call !

Comment: Yes, this in same thread

Comment: You need to add more code for us to debug because as it stands now we can only guess and my guess is that you are not initializing the form correctly.

Comment: Either `workingForm` or `scanLog` are `nil`

Comment: Don't do it like this. Your current module needs to have too much knowledge about the `WorkingForm` internals, i.e. like when `scanLog` is available or not. You should encapsulate that inside the `WorkingForm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a breakpoint on that line, and verify that `workingForm` and `scanLog` are not `nil`.

You should either make sure that they are assigned, or you need to check if they are before you use them.

Comment: +1; Then verify that `Lines` and `Lines.Text` are accessible and you can call the `Add` method on `Lines`.